# How do I filter out a string to contain only letters in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, loops

I was given this string:

```
var myMessage = "Learning is fun!"
```

This is how I attempted to create an array listing only the letters (without the spaces and "!").

```
var myMessage = "Learning is fun!";
var arr1 = myMessage.split("");

function onlyLetters(array){
    let arr2 = []
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] === "a" || "b" || "c" || "d" || "e" 
        || "f" || "g" || "h" || "i" || "j" || "k" || "l" 
        || "m" || "n" || "o" || "p" || "q" || "r" || "s" 
        || "t" || "u" || "v" || "w" || "x" || "y" || "z"){
          arr2.push(array[i])
        }
    }
    return arr2
}

console.log(onlyLetters(myMessage))
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there a shorthand for listing letters "a" through "z"?

Comment: You can't do `array[i] === "a" || "b" || .... ` because the right side of the `===` is evaluated as `"a" || "b" || .... `. What you mean to do is `array[i] === "a" || array[i] === "b" || ...`

Answer (score 7):

A simple way may be to use Regex like so

```
let message = "Learning is fun!";
let onlyLettersArray = message.split('').filter(char => /[a-zA-Z]/.test(char));
console.log(onlyLettersArray)
```

.filter takes an array and runs a function on the elements, which returns true or false. The item is removed if it returns false.
The regex checks if the character is within the range a-z or A-Z

Another way is to filter the char and then split it like so

```
let message = "Learning is fun!";
let onlyLettersArray = message.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, '').split('');
console.log(onlyLettersArray)
```

**Edit:**

```
var myMessage = "Learning is fun!";
var arr1 = myMessage.split("");

function onlyLetters(array){
    let arr2 = []
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(/[a-z]/.test(array[i])){ // you can use regex instead of all characters
          arr2.push(array[i])
        }
    }
    return arr2
}

console.log(onlyLetters(myMessage))
```

**Update:**
If instead of an array of characters, you have to replace special chars in a string, you can write

```
let message = "Learning is fun!";
let letterMessage = message.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gm,"")
console.log(letterMessage)
```

Comment: I'd argue that since OP is a beginner, it is more helpful to them to help with their existing code rather than give them something new.

Comment: I have given the explanation as well. I believe it may be a good way for them to learn the features javascript can offer as well. But you do have a valid point and I will update the code to add what the OP has used

Comment: I think he wanted an array of characters based on the question. If it is a string, you could replace the special chars @AZ_

Comment: He hasn't used a join() in the end

Comment: You can also do `message.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, '').split('')`

Comment: yeah @ninesalt that makes more sense too

Answer (score 2):

You simply can use `String.prototype.match` to get the array of letters only.

```js
let arr = "Learning is fun!  1233  ashdgahsgdh".match(/[A-Za-z]/g);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: it is String.prototype.match. Not array

Comment: @DhananjaiPai oops! typo

Answer (score 0):

You could take a lower case string, split it and check each character if the value is greater or equal to `'a'` and smaller or equal to `'z'`.

Ath the end, after filtering, you could get a string back by joining the array with an empty string as glue.

```js
function onlyLetters(string) {
    return string
        .toLowerCase()
        .split("")
        .filter(c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        .join('');
}

console.log(onlyLetters("Learning is fun!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since OP is a beginner, I would propose another solution that doesn't use regex

```
var myMessage = "Learning is fun!";
var arr1 = myMessage.split("");

function onlyLetters(array){
let arr2 = []
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(isLetter(array[i])){
      arr2.push(array[i])
    }
}
   return arr2
}

function isLetter(c) {
   return c.toLowerCase() != c.toUpperCase();
}
```